# Justification that a function is well defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

> Let $n:\nabla^1\to I$ be the homeomorphism
>
> $(1-t)e_0+te_1\mapsto t$. There exist a well defined function $\psi:\pi_1(X,x_0)\to H_1(X)$ where $[\sigma]\mapsto[\sigma\circ n]$.

Now consider the following diagram (sorry because it looks so ugly)

\begin{array}{ccccccccc} S^1 &   \\
\uparrow{u(t)=e^{2\pi i t}} & \searrow{\sigma'\simeq \gamma'} &  \\
I & \xrightarrow{\sigma\simeq \gamma} & X &  
\end{array}

We then have $\sigma_*':H_1(S^1)\to H_1(X)$ where

$cls(\sum m_i\delta_i)\mapsto \sum m_icls(\sigma\circ\delta_i)$.

And also

$[\sigma\circ n]=[\sigma'\circ u\circ n]=\sigma_*'[u\circ n]\in H_1(X)$

$[\gamma\circ n]=[\gamma'\circ u\circ n]=\gamma_*'[u\circ n]\in H_1(X)$

Please if someone could justify this equality $[\sigma\circ n]=[\sigma'\circ u\circ n]$ (I think it follows from the diagram because $\sigma'\circ u=\sigma$) and what exactly needs  to be proved, I did not understand nothing in class.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You really need to explain what you're talking about. What is $\nabla^1$? What is $X$? What does "$(1-t)e_0+te_1\mapsto t$" have to do with all this? (Is that the definition of $n$? Nothing you wrote indicates that...)

Comment: What is "$cls$"?

Comment: @PaulFrost a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me first try to fill the notational gaps in your question.

$\nabla^1$ is certainly the standard $1$-simplex in $\mathbb R^2$. The elements of $H_1(X)$ are homology classes $[\sum m_i  \delta_i]$ of chains $\sum m_i  \delta_i$, where $\delta_i : \nabla^1 \to X$ are singular $1$-simplices and $m_i \in \mathbb Z$.

If you take a closed path $\sigma: I \to X$ based at $x_0$, you get an induced $\sigma' : S^1 \to X$ such that $\sigma' \circ u = \sigma$. This map induces the homomorphism $\sigma'_* : H_1(S^1) \to H_1(X)$.

*By definition* $\sigma \circ n = \sigma' \circ u \circ n :  \nabla^1 \to X$. Also note $u \circ n :  \nabla^1 \to S^1$. Thus by definition of induced maps
$$\sigma'_*([u \circ n]) = [\sigma' \circ u \circ n] = [\sigma \circ n] .$$

The map $\psi : \pi_1(X,x_0) \to H_1(X)$ is now  defined by
$$\psi([\sigma]) = \sigma'_*([u \circ n]) .$$
It remains to show that $\psi$ is well-defined. That is, if we have a closed path $\gamma: I \to X$ based at $x_0$ which is path-homotopic to $\sigma$, then $\sigma'_*([u \circ n]) = \gamma'_*([u \circ n])$. But this is obvious: Since the paths $\sigma, \gamma$ are path-homotopic, the induced maps $\sigma', \gamma' : S^1 \to X$ are homotopic and therefore $\sigma'_* = \gamma'_*$.